# Nextjs - Auth token stored in memory + refresh token in HTTP Only cookie

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, cookies, next.js

I am currently implementing an authentication flow using [Nextjs](https://nextjs.org) and an api using Expressjs.

I am looking to store a `JWT token` as an auth token `in memory` that I can periodically refresh using a refresh token stored in an `HTTPOnly cookie`.

For my implementation, I took as a reference the nice OSS project [here](https://github.com/vnovick/graphql-jwt-tutorial).

My issue here is that when I am storing the auth token in `inMemoryToken` during login, the value is stored only available client side but still available server side and vice versa.

Another example is when I am disconnecting:

- `inMemoryToken` is equal to something server side
- user click the logout button and `logout()` is called front side and `inMemoryToken = null`
- on page change, `getServerSideProps()` is called on the server but `inMemoryToken` on the server is still equal to the previous value and therefore my user still appear connected.

Here is the `Nextjs` code

```js
//auth.js
import { Component } from 'react';
import Router from 'next/router';
import { serialize } from 'cookie';
import { logout as fetchLogout, refreshToken } from '../services/api';

let inMemoryToken;

export const login = ({ accessToken, accessTokenExpiry }, redirect) => {
    inMemoryToken = {
        token: accessToken,
        expiry: accessTokenExpiry,
    };
    if (redirect) {
        Router.push('/');
    }
};

export const logout = async () => {
    inMemoryToken = null;
    await fetchLogout();
    window.localStorage.setItem('logout', Date.now());
    Router.push('/');
};

const subMinutes = (dt, minutes) => {
    return new Date(dt.getTime() - minutes * 60000);
};

export const withAuth = (WrappedComponent) => {
    return class extends Component {
        static displayName = `withAuth(${Component.name})`;

        state = {
            accessToken: this.props.accessToken,
        };
        async componentDidMount() {
            this.interval = setInterval(async () => {
                inMemoryToken = null;
                const token = await auth();
                inMemoryToken = token;
                this.setState({ accessToken: token });
            }, 60000);
            window.addEventListener('storage', this.syncLogout);
        }

        componentWillUnmount() {
            clearInterval(this.interval);
            window.removeEventListener('storage', this.syncLogout);
            window.localStorage.removeItem('logout');
        }

        syncLogout(event) {
            if (event.key === 'logout') {
                Router.push('/');
            }
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <WrappedComponent
                    {...this.props}
                    accessToken={this.state.accessToken}
                />
            );
        }
    };
};

export const auth = async (ctx) => {
    console.log('auth ', inMemoryToken);
    if (!inMemoryToken) {
        inMemoryToken = null;
        const headers =
            ctx && ctx.req
                ? {
                      Cookie: ctx.req.headers.cookie ?? null,
                  }
                : {};
        await refreshToken(headers)
            .then((res) => {
                if (res.status === 200) {
                    const {
                        access_token,
                        access_token_expiry,
                        refresh_token,
                        refresh_token_expiry,
                    } = res.data;
                    if (ctx && ctx.req) {
                        ctx.res.setHeader(
                            'Set-Cookie',
                            serialize('refresh_token', refresh_token, {
                                path: '/',
                                expires: new Date(refresh_token_expiry),
                                httpOnly: true,
                                secure: false,
                            }),
                        );
                    }
                    login({
                        accessToken: access_token,
                        accessTokenExpiry: access_token_expiry,
                    });
                } else {
                    let error = new Error(res.statusText);
                    error.response = res;
                    throw error;
                }
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                console.log(e);
                if (ctx && ctx.req) {
                    ctx.res.writeHead(302, { Location: '/auth' });
                    ctx.res.end();
                } else {
                    Router.push('/auth');
                }
            });
    }
    const accessToken = inMemoryToken;
    if (!accessToken) {
        if (!ctx) {
            Router.push('/auth');
        }
    }
    return accessToken;
};
```

```js
//page index.js

import Head from 'next/head';
import { Layout } from '../components/Layout';
import { Navigation } from '../components/Navigation';
import { withAuth, auth } from '../libs/auth';

const Home = ({ accessToken }) => (
    <Layout>
        <Head>
            <title>Home</title>
        </Head>
        <Navigation />
        <div>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
                eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut
                enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
                nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
                in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
                nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,
                sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </p>
        </div>
    </Layout>
);

export const getServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {
    const accessToken = await auth(ctx);
    return {
        props: { accessToken: accessToken ?? null },
    };
};

export default withAuth(Home);
```

Part of the express js code:

```js
app.post('/api/login', (req, res) => {
    const { username, password } = req.body;

    ....

    const refreshToken = uuidv4();
    const refreshTokenExpiry = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 10 * 60 * 1000);

    res.cookie('refresh_token', refreshToken, {
        maxAge: 10 * 60 * 1000,
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: false,
    });

    res.json({
        access_token: accessToken,
        access_token_expiry: accessTokenExpiry,
        refresh_token: refreshToken,
        user,
    });
});

app.post('/api/refresh-token', (req, res) => {
    const refreshToken = req.cookies['refresh_token'];
    
    .....

    const newRefreshToken = uuidv4();
    const newRefreshTokenExpiry = new Date(
        new Date().getTime() + 10 * 60 * 1000,
    );

    res.cookie('refresh_token', newRefreshToken, {
        maxAge: 10 * 60 * 1000,
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: false,
    });

    res.json({
        access_token: accessToken,
        access_token_expiry: accessTokenExpiry,
        refresh_token: newRefreshToken,
        refresh_token_expiry: newRefreshTokenExpiry,
    });
});

app.post('/api/logout', (_, res) => {
    res.clearCookie('refresh_token');
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

What I understand is that even if the `let inMemoryToken` is declared once, two separate instance of it will be available at runtime, one client side and one server side, and modifying on doesn't affect the other.
Am I right?

In this case, how to solved this since the auth method can be called on the server but also on the client?

Answer (score 3):

I went and created an example that shows how you can use sessions to store information in memory for individual users across requests. You can check out the codesandbox at the bottom if you are just interested in the code.

There are two things to keep in mind:

1. you can't directly access variables declared on your server on your client
2. variables declared on the server in the global scope are shared across requests

However, you can use a common ID stored in a cookie on the client and store data in memory and access it via a session on the request.

When you have a request incoming, you can check to see if the cookie exists on request's header, if it exists try to load the session from memory, if it doesn't exists or can't be loaded, create a new session.

```
| Incoming Request
|   |--> Check the cookie header for your session key
|       |--> If cookie exists load cookie
|       |--> Else create session + use 'set-cookie' header to tell the client it's session key
|          |--> Do stuff with the data stored in the session
```

To be able to do that, we need to have some way to store the sessions and the data associated with them. You said that you just want to store the data in memory.

```
const memoryStore = new Map();
```

Okay now we have are memory store, but how do we make it persist across requests? Let's store it as a global object.

```
const MEMORY_STORE = Symbol.for('__MEMORY_STORE');
const getMemoryStore = () => {
  if (!global[MEMORY_STORE]) {
    global[MEMORY_STORE] = new Map();
  }
  return global[MEMORY_STORE];
};
```

Perfect, now we can call `getMemoryStore` to access the persisted data. Now we want to create a handler that tries to load the session from the request, otherwise creating a new session.

```
const SESSION_KEY = '__my_session_id';

const loadSession = (req, res) => {
  const memory = getMemoryStore();

  const cookies = parseCookies(req.headers.cookie);
  const cookieSession = cookies[SESSION_KEY];

  // check to make sure that cookieSession is defined and that it exists in the memory store
  if (cookieSession && memory.has(cookieSession)) {
    const session = memory.get(cookieSession);
    req.session = session;
    
    // do something with the session

  } else {
    // okay the session doesn't exists so we need to create one, create the unique session id
    const sessionId = uuid();
    const session = { id: sessionId };
    memory.set(sessionId, session);
   
    // set the set-cookie header on the response with the session ID
    res.setHeader('set-cookie', `${SESSION_KEY}=${sessionId}`);

    req.session = session;
  }  
};
```

Now we can call that anywhere on the server side and it will load or create the session. For instance, you can call it from `getServerSideProps`

```
export const getServerSideProps = ({ req, res }) => {
  loadSession(req, res);

  // our session exists on req.session !! 
  
  return { props: { ... } };
};
```

I made a codesandbox that has a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-water-biicc?file=/utils/app.js

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have been checking at your code but are still not sure that this is solving the problem since that while calling `/login` or `/refreshToken` from the client side, there is no way I can modify the current value in memory by the one given by the api. I am seeing that my question might be obscure about that point so I'll edit it see if I can also provide a simplified code sandbox.

Comment: @Florian_L I may be misunderstanding, but you shouldn't need to explicitly modify anything on the client side. That is automatically done for you through the `set-cookie` header. On your client you don't need to explicitly store the refresh_token, that is stored in the browser's cookies. Since it's an http cookie, it's automatically sent to the server by the browser.

Comment: In the case of a user login in, the fetch request takes place client side.You get back the refresh token as an httpOnly cookie so you don’t have to care about that one but the access_token is sent as json client side, what do you do with it? Another situation is when you refresh the token. Let’s say your access token expires every 5min. The user arrive on a page so the access token get passed from the server to the client side, then if no page change for 5 min the refresh token is refreshed on the client. Those that mean that you should refresh the token on every page change?

Comment: Maybe I am over complication on that and couldn’t a secure approach to deal with authentication using SSR with that kind of short and long life token like that. With previous experience with SPA I might also be too focus to reproduce it in SSR where another method might be used.

Comment: Do you have 2 servers overall (your nextjs server + the JWT server from the example) or 3 (next, JWT + some other server JWT talks to)?

Comment: Yes there are currently 2 servers, the one on next js and the detached express one providing the product api (authentication, business api, etc)